# Second request receives the first one that was still processing

Tags: javascript

I have a request system where two unrelated functions are making requests to my server. But the problem is the response is not correct let me explain what is happening step by step:

```
A background function makes a request to the server
Server processes task 1
A second unrelated background function makes a request to the server
Client recieves response of task 1
The second function recieves that response that was for the first function. 
The first function never gets a response.
```

Now i don't know how to solve it, but i know i need to distinguish them separately so theres no conflictions here.

This is my current code that handles the request stuff:

```
function call_back(result,func){
        if(typeof(func) != 'undefined' || func != false){       
            func(result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}

function caller(url,cfunc){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
}

function call_file(url,func){ //handles html files (not json_encoded)
    caller(url,function(){
        if ( xmlhttp.readyState== 4 && xmlhttp.status== 200 ){
            call_back(xmlhttp.responseText,func);
        }
    });
}

function call_data(url,func,JsonBool){ //handles json_encoded data 
    caller(url,function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        call_back(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText),func);               
        }
    });                                           
}
```

What can i do to my functions, for preventing this behaviour?

Comment: This wheel has already been invented. Look for "promises". In jQuery you have "deferreds" but there are standalone libraries like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: I have no interest in using a library other than my own. I learn less if i just go straight to using a library without learning the language.

Comment: My point is that you learn about the "promise pattern" in JavaScript. It's a well known pattern for handling consecutive AJAX requests. I learn a lot by looking at the source code of great libraries, and by using those libraries until you get your "oh I get it" moment and then you can make your own library.

Comment: Also, TBH, not using an AJAX library, specially if you want to support old browsers, is a pain in the ass. It's like programming in Notepad.

Comment: There must be a tutorial / guide on the internet that is easier than dissecting many lines of code. I'm not supporting old browsers its all html5.

Comment: Well, I would suggest these links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises, http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A and also check how an API for promises might look like http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: I'm determined to find a non library version so i can actually read and understand it.

Comment: Promises don't depend on AJAX so the idea is to abstract it so it works with any async code, like a `setTimeout` for example. If I were to do this from scratch I would start with 2 methods `when` and `then` and keep building up from there.

Comment: So using a setTimeout to wait until making the next request?

Comment: I meant that `setTimeout` is asynchronous too, so if you're going to take the challenge and build your own library for promises, then you can test it by using timeouts.

Comment: Btw, there are implementations of the spec in less than 200 LOC. Check here: https://github.com/malko/D.js, https://github.com/timjansen/PinkySwear.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could structure your code - I have used this, it works, but it could be refined.

```
function Ajax(url, callback,args){
  var xhttp = init();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = process;

  function init() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
      return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  function process() {
    if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
      if (callback) callback(xhttp.responseText,args);
      else return xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  this.Get=function(){
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send(null);
  }
}
```

To use it:

```
var url = '/someurl';
var ajax = new Ajax(url,yourCallback,parameters); 
ajax.Get();
```

I believe DRobinson was talking about something like this but more robust. This should be a good example to get you started though.

Comment: Exactly: note the xhttp is set as a variable scoped to the Ajax function, so as not to be overwritten by succeeding XHR requests. Basically that's what I believe was the issue with your code, Dave.

Comment: Ok so setting it up as new and the scope being in the Ajax function means they are different even though same variable name.

Comment: @Dave, that is correct. They will be different objects but have the same constructor.

Comment: @fbynite i should mention the ready state and status always stay at 0 so it never calls the callback. Nor does it show a xhr request in my browser

Comment: I mixed my set up with your code i can show you a pastie: http://jsfiddle.net/gAAg5/1/ it wont work in jsfiddle but you might stop the mistake maybe? @fbynite

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you're using a global/window variable for `xmlhttp`. If this is the case, certain parts of the second call will overwrite the first. Consider using an Object Oriented approach, or otherwise instantiating these as vars in different scopes.

Comment: Where/how would i make it localised?

Comment: One potential way would be to wrap the entire thing, have a var xmlhttp for the wrapped scope and instantiate it for each request. However, I would consider rewriting it with prototypes and have such variables be parameters for the prototyped object that you create. Perhaps an XHR object, or some other name as available.

Comment: Hmm not sure i understand what you mean by wrap

Comment: e.g. you might put `function initiateXHR(whatever_args){ var xmlhttp; ` at the start and `}` at the end, and somewhere in between have it call your call_file/call_data functions based on the args. This way xmlhttp would be a variable that exists once per "initiateXHR" call. Again, though, it would make more sense to look up Object Oriented modeling, perhaps Prototypes: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Comment: (Prototyping is pure Javascript, doesn't require libraries or other code. Do consider it :))

Comment: Any chance you can do an example so i can see the difference, i'll understand it best that way?

Comment: I do not have an example specifically for writing XHR handlers, but here's something generic for the basics - it outlines some simple practices that you can try to redesign your process to follow: http://helephant.com/2009/01/18/javascript-object-prototype/